# What are these method parameters called in Swift?

Tags: methods, syntax, swift

I'm just taking my first steps with Swift and after having worked with things like PHP, Ruby, JavaScript and Python, this is all totally new to me.

So, I have code like this:

```
class DerpController: NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate {
    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse) {
        println("response received")
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!) {
        println("data received")
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
        println("request finished")
    }
}
```

What are these things called: `didReceiveResponse`, `didReceiveData`? Are they some kind kind of message identifier or what?

And is `func connection` one overloaded method or are there actually two that are identified by these "didReceive..." names?

Comment: Oh so now you're changing the code in the question?

Comment: I fixed a typo. what's wrong with that?

Comment: Because my answer was about that typo. As I said (rightly), if that had been your code, the second method would never be called.

Comment: Yes, and you were right about that. So I fixed the typo because that was not the point of my question. Where is the problem?

Comment: The whole question was (and still is) misposed. Without that identity, your phrase `didReceiveResponse`, `didReceiveResponse` is meaningless. And without that identity, there is no question of "overloaded" methods.

Comment: Now that I have the answer to my actual question,  i have fixed the title. True, this has nothing to do with overloading itself but I thought it would when I wrote the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`didReceiveResponse` is an external parameter name. `response` and `data` are local parameter names.

This means that the first function is called with `myDerpController.connection(url, didReceiveResponse:response)`. But within the body of the function you refer to the parameter as `response`.

The second function is a typo, and should be `didReceiveData`

Comment: Ah ok, so it's just a "translation" between the two parameter names. That makes sense. So, if i just write "didReceiveReponse" instead of "didReceiveRepsonse response" then the local variable will just be named "didReceiveResponse", right?

Comment: That's right. Only of course you wouldn't want to do that, as you want a noun rather than a phrase for the local variable. The whole thing is just to make it so that it's easy to emulate the calling style of Objective-C.

Comment: And in fact, the method is overloaded by the different types of the parameters. the internal/external name are just for convenience as I understand it.

Comment: No that's not correct. The external parameter names form part of the function signature. If the parameter types are the same, you'll find that to avoid a duplicate function error you need different external parameter names. It's very important that this is the case for interoperating with Objective-C.

Comment: Ok, so functions with the same name in Swift are overloaded by having different external parameter names and that maps to functions with entirely different names in Ocj-C.

Comment: If you like. But there's really no mapping. The signature of the function/method used by the linker is the same whether it's Swift or Objective-C. The function name really does include all the external parameter names (separated by colons).

Comment: I meant "mapping" in terms of "in my head" not as "in the compiler/linker" :)

Answer (score 0):

These are delegate methods defined by [NSURLConnectionDataDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connection%3adidReceiveResponse%3a), which is a protocol you have adopted.

In Swift, a parameter can have both an internal (parameter, local) name and an external (argument, caller) name. The internal name (`response:`, `data:`) is entirely up to you; the name provided by the docs and by code completion is just a "serving suggestion". The external name, however, needs to match the selector name by which Objective-C (or any other caller) will seek it. The method is called e.g. `connection:didReceiveData:` so you *must* use an external name `didReceiveData` for the second parameter in order to be called.

You also asked (irrelevantly) about overloading. Overloading by type is legal in Swift but not in Objective-C; the latter uses names (selectors) alone. You're biting off a lot at once here because you've chosen to start with an example involving heavy interplay between Swift and Objective-C, to understand which you really need to know at least the rudiments of *both* languages.